# Прибавить к дате 15 минут

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как прибавить к дате 15 минут? Пытаюсь таким способом, но не выходит

```
let date = new Date();
let h = date.getHours(),
    m = date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 15),
    res = h + ':' + m;

$('.you-loan .js-loan').html(' ' + res);
```

Comment: вы сначала измените значения, а потом уже извлекайте `h` и `m` которые выводите. да и в документации что-то не видно что `setMinutes` возвращает что-либо.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот так работает:

```js
    var CurrentTime = new Date();
    CurrentTime.setMinutes(CurrentTime.getMinutes() + 15);
    console.log(CurrentTime.getHours()+":"+CurrentTime.getMinutes());
```

Ваша проблема в том, что setMinutes возвращает значение в милисекундах между 1 января 1970 00:00:00 UTC и обновленной датой. Правильнее пользоваться getMinutes().

Кроме того, важно, что `getHours` и `getMinutes` вызываются после изменения даты - а не до того.

Comment: а почему так работает? что именно поменялось по сравнению с кодом в вопросе?

Comment: @Grundy, извлечение часов поменялось... И с минутами косяк был... И  вообще, зачем такой вопрос?

Comment: @Qwertiy, чтобы автор ответа добавил описание в свой ответ :-)

Comment: @Grundy, зачем?)

Comment: @Qwertiy, потому что иначе и вопрос и ответ бесполезны, и их стоило бы удалить!

Comment: @Grundy, это в вопросе код бесполезен, так что сравнение с ним тоже бесполезно. А вот ответ, как прибавить 15 мин - полезен.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а почему код в вопросе бесполезен? он ведь что-то выполняет. Почему вдруг код в ответе стал не бесполезен?

Comment: @Grundy, потому что он не работает и не показывает никакой стандартной ошибки. Единственное, что он делает - это показывает, что автор что-то пытался сделать сам. А код в ответе работает и достаточно короткий, чтобы его не пояснять.

Comment: @Grundy бесполезно пытаться людям объяснить, что просто кусок кода, это не качественный ответ, и что ответ должен нормально разъяснять вопрошающему в чем он не прав, и что надо изменить. Я сегодня уже пытался в другом топике :D

Comment: Добавил объяснение. Но описание проблемы тоже в общем-то не ахти.